# « Se rapporter », « renvoyer », « être lié », « prendre racine », « reposer sur », « faire appel » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles à la Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) qui se rapportent à la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles à la Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) qui renvoient à la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles à la Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) qui sont liées à la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles à la Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) qui prennent racine dans la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles à la Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) qui reposent sur la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles à la Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) qui font appel à la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.

D’autres variantes à proposer? Laissez aller votre imagination!

———————————————————————

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles au sens d’Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini selon le socle de la gravité quantique, dans lequel l’espace serait non pas un continuum (continue) mais granulaire. N’en demeure pas moins des spéculations.

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles au sens d’Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini à en croire le socle spéculatif de la gravité quantique, qui postule que l’espace serait non pas continue mais discret.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Une légère variation sur la 3ème et les dernières:

> Le nombre d’univers parallèles **selon** Hugh Everett ne serait pas infini mais plutôt fini pour des considérations (encore spéculatives) **liées** à la gravité quantique - espace granulaire par opposition à continuum -.